# Math. Batch (missing operand, or missing operator)

Tags: math, batch-file, cmd

```
set /a var=2
(
    set /a %var%=var * 2
    set /a %var%=%var% * 2
    set /a %var%*= 2
)
```

Why does it say its wrong?

I got messages like `Missing operand` and `Missing operator`.
Well, operator is there, though I don't know what's operand.

Yes I searched for answer in here, but non of all solves... St least ones that I saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing the `%` syntax. `%` means `expand the contents of this variable`, which is not what you want to do. You want to store the result of the calculation back into the variable. Just remove the `%` on the left side of the assignment operator.

Try this instead:

```
set /a var=2
@echo %var%
set /a var=%var% * 2
set /a var=%var% * 2
set /a var*= 2
@echo %var%
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats all `:)`

```
set /a var=2
set /a var*=2
```

..value of %var% is `4`.

see [operand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that %var% is syntax for interpreter (shell) and it replaces %var% with value of that variable. And it should happen before any command is called.
Set works with environment variables, so it has to work with them and not their values.
Try set /a var = 2; set /a var = var * 2.
By the way, in "4 + 5" + is the operator and 4,5 are operands (arguments of operator).